# Load Scatter (Line) graphs dynamically from JSON in iOS?

Tags: xcode, uipickerview, core-plot, scatter-plot

I'm new to corePlot and i'm having trouble to plot the graph(Line) dynamically from json when we select a particular row in UIPickerView.
 Here,

```
Line graph with x-axis: Time as 02,03,04,.....
                       y-axis: temperature as 10,20,30,.....



UIPickerView consists of Date(s). for eg: we have 3 rows :
        06-03-2015, 07-03-2015, 08-03-2015
```

and now if we select any particular row in UIPickerView i have to display line graph. I have done with Static data but now i'm getting trouble with dynamic data.

```
    -(void)initialisePlot
{
    // Start with some simple sanity checks before we kick off
    if ( (self.hostingView == nil) || (self.graphData == nil) ) {
        NSLog(@"TUTSimpleScatterPlot: Cannot initialise plot without hosting view or data.");
        return;
    }

    if ( self.graph != nil ) {
        NSLog(@"TUTSimpleScatterPlot: Graph object already exists.");
        return;
    }

    // Create a graph object which we will use to host just one scatter plot.
    CGRect frame = [self.hostingView bounds];


    //CGRect frame = [self.hostingView bounds];

     //CGRect frame = [self.hostingView frame];
    self.graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:frame] ;


    //self.hostingView=[[CPTGraphHostingView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 900.0, 420.0)];
    //self.graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostingView.bounds];

    // Add some padding to the graph, with more at the bottom for axis labels.
    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 20.0f;
    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 10.0f;
    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 50.0f;
    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 60.0f;

    // Tie the graph we've created with the hosting view.
    self.hostingView.hostedGraph = self.graph;

    // If you want to use one of the default themes - apply that here.
    [self.graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]];

    // Create a line style that we will apply to the axis and data line.
    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;

    // Create a text style that we will use for the axis labels.
    CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    textStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica";
    textStyle.fontSize = 14;
    textStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];

    // Create the plot symbol we're going to use.
    CPTPlotSymbol *plotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol crossPlotSymbol];
    plotSymbol.lineStyle = lineStyle;
    plotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(8.0, 8.0);     

    // Setup some floats that represent the min/max values on our axis.
    int xAxisMin = 0;
    int xAxisMax = 20;
    float yAxisMin = 0;
    float yAxisMax = 50;


    // We modify the graph's plot space to setup the axis' min / max values.
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)self.graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(xAxisMin) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(xAxisMax-xAxisMin)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yAxisMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yAxisMax - yAxisMin)];

    // Modify the graph's axis with a label, line style, etc.
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)self.graph.axisSet;

    axisSet.xAxis.title = @"Time";
    axisSet.xAxis.titleTextStyle = textStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.titleOffset = 20;
    axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.labelTextStyle = textStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.labelOffset = 3;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromInt(2);
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLength = 5;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 7;


    axisSet.yAxis.title = @"Temperature";
    axisSet.yAxis.titleTextStyle = textStyle;   
    axisSet.yAxis.titleOffset = 40.0f;  
    axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;    
    axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.labelTextStyle = textStyle;   
    axisSet.yAxis.labelOffset = 3.0f;   
    axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(10.0f);
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
    axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;   

    // Add a plot to our graph and axis. We give it an identifier so that we 
    // could add multiple plots (data lines) to the same graph if necessary.
    CPTScatterPlot *plot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] ;
    plot.dataSource = self;
    plot.identifier = @"mainplot";
    plot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
    plot.plotSymbol = plotSymbol;
    [self.graph addPlot:plot];  
}

// Delegate method that returns the number of points on the plot
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot 
{
    if ( [plot.identifier isEqual:@"mainplot"] ) 
    {
        return [self.graphData count];
    } 

    return 0;
}

// Delegate method that returns a single X or Y value for a given plot.
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if ( [plot.identifier isEqual:@"mainplot"] ) 
    {

        NSValue *value = [self.graphData objectAtIndex:index];
        CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];

        // FieldEnum determines if we return an X or Y value.
        if ( fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX ) 
        {
            return [NSNumber numberWithInt:point.x];
        }
        else    // Y-Axis
        {
            return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:point.y];
        }   
    }

    return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
}
```

In viewDidLoad i'm calling this method as follows:

pickerData=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"28-02-2015",@"01-03-2015",@"02-03-2015",@"03-03-2015",@"04-03-2015", nil];
     NSMutableArray *data1 = [NSMutableArray array];
            [data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)]];

```
    self.scatterPlot = [[TUTSimpleScatterPlot alloc] initWithHostingView:_graphHostingView andData:data1];
    [self.scatterPlot initialisePlot];
```

pickerView datasource and delegate methods as follows with dynamic data:

```
      #pragma mark PickerView DataSource

        - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
        {
            return 1;
        }

        - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
        {
            return pickerData.count;
        }

        - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
        {
            return pickerData[row];
        }

        #pragma mark -
        #pragma mark PickerView Delegate
        -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    //PickerModal *pModal=[picDataArray objectAtIndex:row];

    pickObj=[picDataArray objectAtIndex:row];
    //result=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",pickObj.picDate];

    NSLog(@"time :%@",pickObj.picTime);
    NSLog(@"temp :%@",pickObj.picTemperature);


    for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
        int selectedRow=[self.myPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
        if ((selectedRow=i)) {
            NSMutableArray *data1 = [NSMutableArray array];

            [data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake([pickObj.picTime floatValue], [pickObj.picTemperature floatValue])]];
            NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:data1];

            self.scatterPlot = [[TUTSimpleScatterPlot alloc] initWithHostingView:_graphHostingView andData:arr];
            [self.scatterPlot initialisePlot];

        }

    }

    [pickerView reloadComponent:0];
}
```

i'm parsing json data as :

```
-(void)retrieveData{

    NSString *sensorTagID=@"UIUIA6767672345678910987654321";

    NSMutableString *globalUrlString=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"url"];
    [globalUrlString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?SensorTagID=%@",sensorTagID]];


    NSLog(@"url string:%@",globalUrlString);

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:globalUrlString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *globalRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];

    [globalRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURLResponse *theResponse = [[NSURLResponse alloc]init];

    //connecting to the server
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:globalRequest returningResponse:&theResponse error:&error];

    //NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    picDataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i=0; i<json.count; i++) {

       pickDate=[[json objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"Date"];
        NSLog(@"date %@",pickDate);

        NSArray *getEvents=[[json objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"OnDateSensorValues"];
        for (NSDictionary *eventsObj in getEvents) {
            pickHumidity=eventsObj[@"Humidity"];
            //NSLog(@"humidity %@",pickHumidity);

            pickLocationHumidity=eventsObj[@"LocationHumidity"];
            //NSLog(@"locHumidity %@",pickLocationHumidity);

            pickLocationTemperature=eventsObj[@"LocationTemperature"];
            //NSLog(@"locTemp %@",pickLocationTemperature);

            pickTemperature=eventsObj[@"Temperature"];
            NSLog(@"temp %@",pickTemperature);

            pickTime=eventsObj[@"Time"];
            NSLog(@"time %@",pickTime);


               }

            pickObj=[[PickerModal alloc]initWithPicDate:pickDate andPicHumidity:pickHumidity andPicLocationHumidity:pickLocationHumidity andPicLocationTemperature:pickLocationTemperature andPicTemperature:pickTemperature andPicTime:pickTime];

        [picDataArray addObject:pickObj];

    }

    [self.myPickerView reloadComponent:0];

}
```

json output as follows:

```
[
    {
        "Date": "2015-02-26",
        "OnDateSensorValues": [
            {
                "Humidity": "49",
                "LocationHumidity": "49",
                "LocationTemperature": "45",
                "Temperature": "45",
                "Time": "10"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "48",
                "LocationHumidity": "48",
                "LocationTemperature": "44",
                "Temperature": "44",
                "Time": "11"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "47",
                "LocationHumidity": "47",
                "LocationTemperature": "43",
                "Temperature": "43",
                "Time": "12"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "46",
                "LocationHumidity": "46",
                "LocationTemperature": "42",
                "Temperature": "42",
                "Time": "13"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "45",
                "LocationHumidity": "45",
                "LocationTemperature": "41",
                "Temperature": "41",
                "Time": "14"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Date": "2015-02-27",
        "OnDateSensorValues": [
            {
                "Humidity": "29",
                "LocationHumidity": "29",
                "LocationTemperature": "25",
                "Temperature": "25",
                "Time": "6"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "28",
                "LocationHumidity": "28",
                "LocationTemperature": "24",
                "Temperature": "24",
                "Time": "7"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "27",
                "LocationHumidity": "27",
                "LocationTemperature": "23",
                "Temperature": "23",
                "Time": "8"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "26",
                "LocationHumidity": "26",
                "LocationTemperature": "22",
                "Temperature": "22",
                "Time": "9"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "25",
                "LocationHumidity": "25",
                "LocationTemperature": "21",
                "Temperature": "21",
                "Time": "10"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Date": "2015-02-28",
        "OnDateSensorValues": [
            {
                "Humidity": "31",
                "LocationHumidity": "31",
                "LocationTemperature": "35",
                "Temperature": "35",
                "Time": "22"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "32",
                "LocationHumidity": "32",
                "LocationTemperature": "36",
                "Temperature": "36",
                "Time": "21"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "33",
                "LocationHumidity": "33",
                "LocationTemperature": "37",
                "Temperature": "37",
                "Time": "20"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "34",
                "LocationHumidity": "34",
                "LocationTemperature": "38",
                "Temperature": "38",
                "Time": "19"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "35",
                "LocationHumidity": "35",
                "LocationTemperature": "39",
                "Temperature": "39",
                "Time": "18"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Date": "2015-03-01",
        "OnDateSensorValues": [
            {
                "Humidity": "12",
                "LocationHumidity": "12",
                "LocationTemperature": "16",
                "Temperature": "16",
                "Time": "2"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "13",
                "LocationHumidity": "13",
                "LocationTemperature": "17",
                "Temperature": "17",
                "Time": "1"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "14",
                "LocationHumidity": "14",
                "LocationTemperature": "18",
                "Temperature": "18",
                "Time": "2"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "15",
                "LocationHumidity": "15",
                "LocationTemperature": "19",
                "Temperature": "19",
                "Time": "3"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "16",
                "LocationHumidity": "16",
                "LocationTemperature": "20",
                "Temperature": "20",
                "Time": "4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Date": "2015-03-02",
        "OnDateSensorValues": [
            {
                "Humidity": "32",
                "LocationHumidity": "32",
                "LocationTemperature": "36",
                "Temperature": "36",
                "Time": "20"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "33",
                "LocationHumidity": "33",
                "LocationTemperature": "37",
                "Temperature": "37",
                "Time": "21"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "34",
                "LocationHumidity": "34",
                "LocationTemperature": "38",
                "Temperature": "38",
                "Time": "22"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "35",
                "LocationHumidity": "35",
                "LocationTemperature": "39",
                "Temperature": "39",
                "Time": "23"
            },
            {
                "Humidity": "36",
                "LocationHumidity": "36",
                "LocationTemperature": "40",
                "Temperature": "40",
                "Time": "24"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

from here i would like to take temp,time values and show on graph. But i'm able to plot only one point on the graph. How to get all time and temp values on the graph?....Please help me as i'm struggling with the concept since 1week.

Comment: Have you looked at the Core Plot example apps that demonstrate plotting dates and times?

Comment: yes .....but here i have taken dates and times as simple integers....

Comment: What is the relationship between the number and the date? Is it an offset from a reference date or do you have to do a table lookup to convert back to a date?

Comment: thanks for your reply Eric. I have edited my question. Please find it and help me in plotting all the points on the graph. Thanks in advance...

Comment: What's in the `graphData` array? A Core Plot scatter plot displays pairs of numbers. You somehow have to convert the date and time from the JSON data to a number. [`NSCalendar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/dateFromComponents:) is your friend.